# Converting accelerometer data to activity using ADXL345

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I've currently built out a simple circuit using the Arduino Uno R3 and added in a ADXL345 accelerometer. In addition I've thrown in an RTC for prepending a timestamp using the millis() function.

I've got the data out and I've translated it into something usable - i.e. x/y/z gravity values. But my question is how do I translate that into activities? i.e. walking, running, stationary etc. I've read quite a bit on how to approach it but the variation between one thought process and another has me going around in circles.

Although this isn't necessarily a code question, I will be converting this process to code for tracking my own activities.

Any help, past experience on the subject would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done something like this, but I'm also interested in the subject. What I would probably do as my first step - get the data and graph it. 
Then I expect that a stationary pattern would have smaller bumps - so probably if the levels are under a specific cutoff you can say there is no movement. If the levels go above that cutoff then you have movement and you should be able to detect the "peaks". Calculating the mean time between successive peaks should let you know an aproximate speed. Less speed - likely walking, higher speed - running. Again this is what I think it should be, it might not work with real life data.

Comment: Hi @rslite, Thanks a great first step! I've performed a few rounds of data capture and it looks as though Z-axis is the best method to group activity, X&Y have way too many outliers to be used appropriately. I'm toying around with the idea of rate of change over time which is pretty much the same approach as you've suggested, i.e. keep a running tally of the last 10 or so peaks and average them out, and if they meet a certain criteria, them group it accordingly. Going to knock up some code to do this, but I'm currently using the source code from [link](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9814)